# Remove Characters from String

Tags: c#, string

How do I remove a character from specific character to specific character ...

### Example

```
 string a = " Hello ! {ssd} jksssss";
```

In above string i want to remove character from '{' to '}'

```
 output -- >  `Hello !  jksssss`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f7hht7k.aspx) class in [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c75he57e.aspx), to do the replace. For example:

```
var a = " Hello ! {ssd} jksssss";
var newString = Regex myRegex = new Regex("{{.+}}", "");
myRegex.Replace(a, "");
```

EDIT:

If you want to match multiple occurrances of curly braces, and replace each one, use this regular expression instead:

```
var a = "Hello ! {ssd} jksssss {tasdas}";
Regex myRegex = new Regex("{{[^{]+}}", "");
var newString = myRegex.Replace(a, "");
// a == "Hello !  jksssss "
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
string a = " Hello ! {ssd} jksssss";
string b = Regex.Replace(a, "{\w+}", "");
```

This won't work for `"Hi {!#$#@}!"`, that is left as an excericse :-) Start [at this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more basic information on regular expressions in .NET.

Comment: Remember to add "using System.Text.RegularExpressions;" at the start of your code for this to work.

Comment: abc = Regex.Replace(abc, "{\w+}", ""); // error :Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Yup. Try @"{\w+}" (with the at symbol). That will treat the backslash as a normal character.

Answer (score 4):

One way without using regexp is below:

```
string a = " Hello ! {ssd} jksssss";
int start = a.IndexOf('{');
int end = a.IndexOf('}', start);
if (end > start && start != -1) {
    a = a.Remove(pos, end-start+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex.Replace(), if you don´t want to find the specific positions and the content between braces varies.