# Remove specific characters from string C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, trim

I have got a string `["foo","bar","buzz"]` from view, i want to remove `[`,`"`&,`]`
I have used `string x = tags.Trim(new Char[] { '[', '"', ']' });` but the output i got is `foo","bar","buzz`  instead of `foo,bar,buzz`

[image]

I have tried [Trimming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621673/remove-characters-from-string)
 but still having problem.

Comment: "creative" approach (not recommended): `new string(tags.ToCharArray().Where(c => !"[\"]".Contains(c)).ToArray());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the power of Regex!

```
var x = Regex.Replace(tags, @"(\[|""|\])", "");
```

Comment: var trimmed = Regex.Replace(x, @"(\[|""|\])", ""); Added a second doube quote in the regex due to verbatim string literal. The current answer doesn't compile.

Answer (score 12):

As alternative, you can use a "simple" `Replace`

```
string x = tags.Replace("[","")
               .Replace("\"","")
               .Replace("]","");
```

It isn't fast, but it's simple.

If you need more performance you should use an alternative.

---

*please note:* that each Replace call returns a new string, and with every call the whole string is reevaluated. Although I often use this myself (due to the readability) it's not recommended for complex patterns or very long string values

Comment: I used this but was looking for some better alternative, regex worked for me :)

Comment: To me this "simple" approach is 10x better than regex. Deciphering regex is frustrating and here you can clearly see what is going on. It is readable.

Comment: @A_Name_Does_Not_Matter - that *would* be nice, but it seems there is no overload of [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) takes `char[]` and `string`.

Comment: Yes, there is no overload method... my bad.
@Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd switch your order of operations.  For instance

```
String[] unformattedTags = tags.Split(',');
String[] formattedTags = unformattedTags.Select(itm => itm.Trim( '[','"',']')).ToArray();
```

This removes the restricted characters from each tag individually.

Comment: Also, `Trim` accepts `params`, so you can simply write `String[] formattedTags = tags.Split(',').Select(item => item.Trim('"', '[', ']')).ToArray();` -- no need for `new char[] { ... }`